# shell script Key value compare 2 files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Need help on shell script.

file1.txt

```
ABC1:10
ABC2:20
ABC3:15
```

file2.txt

```
ABC1:20
ABC2:10
ABC3:10
```

I have to compare the 2 files file1.txt and file2.txt .
when key matches from both files, We have to verify the value is greater or equal for that key compared to first file.

when ABC1 matches in 2 files it's value  is compared. 10 (ABC1 in fil1.txt) is less than 20 (ABC2 in file2.txt)  it shouldnt print,  for second ABC2  20 is greater than 10 it has to print in output

when i run the shell script, it has to show below output.

```
ABC2:20
ABC3:15
```

Comment: On SO its highly encourage for users to add their efforts in form or code which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: You say `ABC1:20` should print, but you didn't include it in your output. You do not specify what happens if a value is only in one file, or whether it's possible for a value to occur more than once in either file. Does ordering matter? How big are the files? And most importantly, what have you tried? Please c.f. [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for guidance on asking a good question, and I look forward to helping you out on it once we have all the info we need. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for line1 in $(cat $1)
do
    key=$(echo $line1 | sed -E 's/(.+):.+/\1/')
    val1=$(echo $line1 | sed -E 's/.+:(.+)/\1/')

    for line2 in $(grep $key $2)
    do
        val2=$(echo $line2 | sed -E 's/.+:(.+)/\1/')
        if (( $val2 <= $val1 ))
        then
            echo $line1
        fi
    done
done
```

If you save this as `cmp.sh` and [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi) then you can compare your files with

```sh
$ ./cmp.sh file1.txt file2.txt
```